# Loading components of shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have a zipped shapefile with all components in place. It has a .shp file, a .dbf file and a .shx file.Projection file (.prj) and .sbn and .sbx files are also in place. I have tried loading the zipped file directly, but this has resulted in only .shp rendered.

It is a shapefile describing Bus-Routes through a city centre. Currently, only the streets are showing and I can't see the data contained in the .dbf file when I open attribute table of the layer I have loaded (by loading the zip file).

Any ideas about loading the components individually in QGIS 2.18?

Comment: Have you tried to unzip all and open then the .shp from the directory?

Comment: also you can try add zipped shp from browser panel

Comment: That's what a shapefile looks like

Comment: You definitely should double check that your files are named identically within your zip (routes.shp, routes.shx, routes.dbf, routes.prj, etc.). I was only able to recreate the issue you're describing by misnaming the dbf.